# How to get child class name from parent class

Tags: php, oop, php-5.3, late-static-binding

I'm trying to accomplish this without requiring a function on the child class... is this possible?  I have a feeling it's not, but I really want to be sure...

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        static::who(); // Here comes Late Static Bindings
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test(); //returns B
?>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`get_called_class()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) instead of `__CLASS__`. You'll also be able to replace `static` with `self` as the function will resolve the class through late binding for you:

```
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo get_called_class();
    }
    public static function test() {
        self::who();
    }
}

class B extends A {}

B::test();
```