# How to get child class name from parent class in php

Tags: php, inheritance

```
<?php

class parentClass {

    function myChild() {
        echo 'Child Class Name: '.__CLASS__;
    }   
}

class childClass extends parentClass {

}

$childClassObj = new childClass;

$childClassObj->myChild();
```

The output is

```
Child Class Name: parentClass
```

Actually, I am expecting an output

```
Child Class Name: childClass
```

What should I do to get the output?

Comment: Got answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577984/how-to-get-child-class-name-from-parent-class

Comment: You could override `myChild` in each child but I guess that's not you want

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [get_called_class](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)

```
<?php
    class parentClass {

        function myChild() {
           echo 'Child Class Name: '.get_called_class();
        }   
    }

    class childClass extends parentClass {

    }

    $childClassObj = new childClass;

    $childClassObj->myChild(); //childClass
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
function myChild() {
   echo 'Child Class Name: '.get_class($this);
}
```